# Mock out auth session while recording test

Tags: next.js, playwright, next-auth

I am using [PlayWright](https://playwright.dev/) to record a test in a NextJs app. The app uses [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/) for authentication. Is there a way to mock out `useSession` and `getSession` so that the mocked object is used both in the client and during server side rendering while recording the test?